# Update managed object context in background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

On my iPhone I use a managed object context (MOC) in a background thread to synchronize messages from my server with the messages stored in my database. To prevent duplicates I fetch the ids of the new messages using predicates and check if these messages are already in the database. After the import is finished I merge the MOC on the background thread with my default MOC on the main thread. So far so good.

But if the user creates a new message on the main thread **while** the messages are synchronized  (and I already did the fetch on the background MOC to check for duplicates) how can I update the background MOC to prevent duplicate messages?

Best Regards
Carsten

Answer (score 0):

You can get notified of the changes in the main thread by observing **NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(updateMessages:)
    name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
    object:mainManagedObjectContext];
```

Your **updateMessages:** method takes a NSNotification parameter:

```
- (void)updateMessages:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [myManagedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

You can use **[notification userInfo]** for finer-grained info on the update.

Comment: As far as I understood the notification is posted on the thread that created it. My import runs in a NSOperation. How would I call the updateMessages method on the background thread (I do not know how to obtain the reference to the background thread to call performSelector:onThread...)?

Comment: You can use performBlock: on myManagedObjectContext to have the merge run in its own queue. Just make sure you when you create it to use initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.